# Javascript cookie not expiring

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have created a cookie using javascript. In Google chrome console (Application tab) I can see that cookie exipration time is passed but the cookie exists in the list yet:

```
var tempdate = new Date();
tempdate .setTime(tempdate.getTime() + (60 * 1000));
document.cookie = "lock=done; expires="+tempdate ;
```

Expiration time for cookie in the list is:  2019-03-03T  **17:20:38.000Z**

and console log for date shows: 2019-03-03T  **17:25:41.984Z**

When I set cookies using ASP or PHP it is automatically removed from this list when cookie is expires.

**Edit:** This is how I test the existance of cookie:

```
<a onclick="check()">Check Again</a>
<script>
function check(){
   $.ajax({
    url:"check.asp",
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data); //Prints "lock"
    }
   })
}
</script>
```

And this is Check.asp:

```
response.clear
if request.cookies("lock")="done" then response.write "lock"
response.end
```

Comment: Cookies are not sent to the server when expired, but are not necessarily deleted. An expired cookie may be or may not be deleted depending on the browser and user settings

Comment: Thank you. But it seems it is still working. I have set it to disable a button and it is  working yet @Adrien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution using `toUTCString()` but I have no idea why UTC time should affect cookies(!) :

I am testing on localhost and my own computer time is 2019-03-03  **18:45**

```
var tempdate = new Date();
tempdate .setTime(tempdate.getTime() + (60 * 1000));
document.cookie = "lock=done; expires="+tempdate.toUTCString() ;
```

sets: 2019-03-03T**15:15:07**.000Z as expiration time and it works fine and **expires after 1 minute**.

```
var tempdate = new Date();
tempdate .setTime(tempdate.getTime() + (60 * 1000));
document.cookie = "lock=done; expires="+tempdate;
```

sets 2019-03-03T**18:45:07**.000Z and **not expires after 1 minute** however my computer time is showing 18:45 !

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to yours I found the solution here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Adding the "path = /;" (some browser does not delete the cookie if the path is not indicated).
Hope this will help you.